# Deleting rows from DataTable gives "String binding is invalid"

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable that is filled with values one of which is a DateTime.  I wish to delete rows from this table based on a criteria where anything older than "spotTime" is deleted.  The problem is that it seems to be inconsistent in it's actions and if I turn on the VS debugger, I get an error that the string binding is invalid.  If I try to work in debug mode, the program just closes with that error and never reaches the catch statement.  However, running in non-debug mode, it doesn't always seem to delete the rows. I have tried a few approaches and non seem to work right.  Here is the code.  This is a timer that fires once a minute.

```
    public void ageTimer_Elapsed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            spotAge = Convert.ToDouble(Properties.Settings.Default.SpotAge);

            //Select all rows in datatable where the age is older than spotAge and delete them.
            //date is stored in dt as 20:12:2017: 21:49:02 derived from DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd:MM:yyyy: HH:mm:ss")

            //spotTime is the time from the table
            DateTime spotTime;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                spotTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["date"]), "dd:MM:yyyy: HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                if (spotTime.AddMinutes(spotAge) <= DateTime.UtcNow)
                {
                    dt.Rows[i].Delete();
                }

                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            updateDisplay("");
        }

        catch (Exception x)
        {

        }

    }
```

Removing the dt.Rows[i].Delete() gets rid of the error but of course then I don't get what I need. I must be doing this incorrectly but I cannot seem to debug it.  Any suggestions? Thanks, Tom

Comment: Post the actual complete exception message `the string binding is invalid` sounds like nonsense

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00007ffc2fc33fb8 in Test.exe: 0xC0020001: The string binding is invalid.  It coule be that this message has nothing to do with this code but if I remove the row delete it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops tend to get really antsy when you try to delete elements from them while you are looping through.  You might try getting the count into an independent integer, and then going through the loop in *reverse* order so that when you remove things, it isn't affecting the count adversely.  For example:

`int counter = dt.Rows.Count;
    for (var i = counter-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ... the rest of your code
    }`

Comment: better put DateTime.UtcNow in a variable before loop

Comment: No difference at all using reverse order.

Comment: It would seem that a combination of these two items, has not resolved the Srtring Binding error when in debug mode, but there no longer seems to be any issues with row deletions when I run in non-debug mode.  I have added code to write any errors caught by the catch to a file.  I will let this run for an hour or so to see what happens.

Comment: After a few hours of running there are no more issues.  Thanks for all the help.